# Bitwise operation on tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, bit-manipulation

I am looking to reduce the precision of a TensorFlow tensor using bitwise operations. For example, with a NumPy array, this can be achieved by the following,

```
a = np.array(5) # =[5]
b = np.right_shift(a, 1)  # =[2]
c = np.left_shift(b, 1)  # =[4]
```

Is there a way to do this with TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on the Tensorflow website:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bitwise

> ```
> tf.bitwise.left_shift(x, y, name=None)
> ```
>
> **x**: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int8, int16, int32,
> int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64.
>
> **y**: A Tensor. Must have the same type as x.
>
> **name**: A name for the operation (optional).

Here's an example:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import bitwise_ops
import tensorflow as tf
dtype = tf.int8
lhs = tf.constant([5], dtype=dtype)
rhs = tf.constant([1], dtype=dtype)

right_shift_result = bitwise_ops.right_shift(lhs, rhs)
tf.print(right_shift_result)
left_shift_result = bitwise_ops.left_shift(right_shift_result, rhs)
tf.print(left_shift_result)
```

Out:

```
[2]
[4]
```